# Getting std::bad_alloc in Release but not in Debug

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, neural-network, operator-overloading

I just don't know what to do with it...

The functions runs well in debug, but not in release.

I am trying to learn about artificial neural networks and C++ vectors.

Here is the code (in Python 2.7) that I'm writing in C++:

http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html#exercise_852508

(just scroll a little to reach it)

I'm using MinGW 7.2.0 from MSYS2 (C++11).

There are some "teste" prints inside the backpropagation method, that is where the problem is comming from (I guess). I also overloaded operators +, - and * to make things easier.

I know that there are some libs like Armadillo that could make things easier, but I really wanna use this problem to learn better.

And here is the files:

### neuralnetwork.h

(I made everything public to make things easier to look at)

```
#define MIN_NUMBER_TOLERANCE 1e-8

namespace nn
{
    class neuralnetwork
    {
    //private:
    public:
        //total number of weights. useful to reserve memory
        int numWeights;
        //total number of biases. useful to reserve memory
        int numBiases;
        //total number of layers: 1 for input, n hidden layers and 1 for output
        int numLayers;
        //a vector to store the number of neurons in each layer: 0 index is about the input layer, last index is about the output layer
        std::vector<int> sizes;
        //stores all biases: num of neurons of layer 1 + ... + num of neurons of layer (numLayers - 1) (input layer has no bias)
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> biases;
        //stores all weights: (num of neurons of layer 1) x (num of neurons of layer ) + ... + ( num of neurons of layer (numLayers - 1) ) x ( num of neurons of layer (numLayers - 2) ) (input layer has no bias)
        std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> weights;
        //stores the output of each neuron of each layer
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> layersOutput;

        std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> derivativeWeights;
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> derivativeBiases;

        std::default_random_engine generator;
        std::normal_distribution<double> distribution;

        double randomNormalNumber(void);

        double costDerivatives(const double&, const double&);

        std::vector<double> costDerivatives(const std::vector<double> &, const std::vector<double> &);

        void backPropagation(const std::vector<double>& neuralNetworkInputs, const std::vector<double>& expectedOutputs, // inputs
                      std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>& derivativeWeights, std::vector<std::vector<double>>& derivativeBiases); // outputs

        void update_mini_batch( const std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<double>,std::vector<double>>> & mini_batch, double eta);

    //public:

        neuralnetwork(const std::vector<int>& sizes);

        std::vector<double> feedforward(const std::vector<double>&);
    };


    std::vector<double> sigmoid(const std::vector<double> &);
    double sigmoid(double);
    std::vector<double> sigmoid_prime(const std::vector<double> &);
    //double sigmoid_prime(double);


}
```

### neuralnetwork.cpp

```
#include "neuralnetwork.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <algorithm>

namespace nn
{
    int counter = 0;

    neuralnetwork::neuralnetwork(const std::vector<int> &sizes)
    {
        this->distribution = std::normal_distribution<double>( 0.0 , 1.0 );

        this->numLayers = sizes.size();
        this->sizes = sizes;

        this->numWeights = 0;
        this->numBiases = 0;

        for ( int i = 1 ; i < this->numLayers ; i++ )
        {
            numWeights += this->sizes[ i ] * this->sizes[ i - 1 ];
            numBiases += this->sizes[ i ];
        }

        this->weights.reserve( numWeights );
        this->biases.reserve( numBiases );

        this->derivativeWeights.reserve( numWeights );
        this->derivativeBiases.reserve( numBiases );

        this->layersOutput.reserve( this->sizes[ 0 ] + numBiases );

        std::vector<double> auxVectorWeights;
        std::vector<std::vector<double> > auxMatrixWeights;

        std::vector<double> auxVectorBiases;

#ifdef DEBUG_BUILD
        std::cout << "debugging!\n";
#endif

        //just to accommodate the input layer with null biases and inputs (makes things easier to iterate and reading :D).
        this->layersOutput.push_back( std::vector<double>( this->sizes[ 0 ] ) );
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrixNothing( 0 );
        this->weights.push_back( matrixNothing );
        this->biases.push_back( std::vector<double>( 0 ) );

        //since the second layer (index 1) because there is no weights (nor biases) for the neurons of the first layer
        for ( int layer = 1 ; layer < this->numLayers ; layer++ )
        {
            //preallocate memory for the output of each layer.
            layersOutput.push_back( std::vector<double>( this->sizes[ layer ] ) );

            //-----------weights begin--------------
            //auxMatrixWeights will store the weights connections between one layer (number of columns) and its subsequent layer (number of rows)
            //auxMatrixWeights = new std::vector(this->sizes[layer], std::vector<double>( this->sizes[layer - 1] )); // it is not working...

            //size[layer] stores the number of neurons on the layer
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < this->sizes[ layer ] ; i++ )
            {
                //auxVectorWeights will have the size of the amount of wights necessary to connect the neuron i (from this layer) to neuron j (from next layer)
                auxVectorWeights = std::vector<double>( this->sizes[ layer - 1 ] );


                for ( int j = 0 ; j < auxVectorWeights.size() ; j++ )
                {
                    auxVectorWeights[ j ] = this->randomNormalNumber();
                }

                auxMatrixWeights.push_back( auxVectorWeights );
            }

            this->weights.push_back( auxMatrixWeights );

            auxMatrixWeights.clear();

            //-----------weights end----------------


            //-----------biases begin---------------
            auxVectorBiases = std::vector<double>( this->sizes[ layer ] );

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < auxVectorBiases.size() ; i++ )
            {
                auxVectorBiases[ i ] = this->randomNormalNumber();
            }

            this->biases.push_back( auxVectorBiases );
            //-----------biases end-----------------
        }

#ifdef _DEBUG
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < this->weights.size() ; i++ )
        {
            std::cout << "layer " << i << "\n";
            for ( int j = 0 ; j < this->weights[ i ].size() ; j++ )
            {
                std::cout << "neuron" << j << std::endl;
                for ( const auto k : this->weights[ i ][ j ] )
                {
                    std::cout << '\t' << k << ' ';
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
#endif
    }

    template <class T>
    inline int lastIndex(std::vector<T> vector , int tail)
    {
        return (vector.size() - tail);
    }

    double neuralnetwork::randomNormalNumber(void)
    {
        return this->distribution( this->generator );
    }

    double sigmoid(double z)
    {
        return 1.0 / ( 1.0 + exp( -z ) );
    }

    std::vector<double> sigmoid(const std::vector<double> & z)
    {
        int max = z.size();
        std::vector<double> output;
        output.reserve(max);

        for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
        {
            output.push_back(0);
            output[i] = 1.0 / ( 1.0 + exp( -z[i] ) );
        }

        return output;
    }

    /*double sigmoid_prime(double z)
    {
        return sigmoid( z ) * ( 1 - sigmoid( z ) );
    }*/

    std::vector<double> sigmoid_prime(const std::vector<double>& z)
    {
        int max = z.size();
        std::vector<double> output;
        output.reserve(max);

        for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
        {
            output.push_back(sigmoid( z[i] ) * ( 1 - sigmoid( z[i] ) ) );
        }

        return output;
    }

    //scalar times vector
    std::vector<double> operator* (double a , const std::vector<double> & b)
    {
        int size = b.size();

        std::vector<double> result(size);

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
        {
            result[i] = a * b[ i ];
        }

        return result;
    }

    // inner product
    std::vector<double> operator* (const std::vector<double> & a , const std::vector<double> & b)
    {

#ifdef _DEBUG
        assert(a.size() == b.size());
#endif

        int size = a.size(); // or b.size(). they should have the same size.

        std::vector<double> result;
        result.reserve(size); // or b.size(). they should have the same size.


        for ( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
        {
            result.push_back( a[ i ] * b[ i ] );
        }

        return result;
    }

    //matrix times columns vector
    std::vector<double> operator* (const std::vector<std::vector<double>> & a , const std::vector<double> & b)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        assert(a[0].size() == b.size());

        for(int i = 0 ; i < ( lastIndex( a , 1 )) ; i++)
        {
            assert(a[i].size() == a[i+1].size());
        }
#endif

        int lines = a.size();
        int columns = a[0].size();

        std::vector<double> result;
        result.reserve(lines);

        int j = 0;

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < lines ; i++ )
        {
            result.push_back(0);
            for(j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++)
            {
                result[i] += a[ i ][ j ] * b[ j ];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    //scalar times matrix (calls scalar times vector)
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> operator* (double a , const std::vector<std::vector<double>> & b)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        for(int i = 0 ; i < b.size()-1 ; i++)
        {
            assert(b[i].size() == b[i+1].size());
        }
#endif

        int lines = b.size();
        int columns = b[0].size();

        std::vector<std::vector<double>> result;

        int j = 0;

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < lines ; i++ )
        {
            result.push_back(a * b[ j ]);
        }

        return result;
    }

    std::vector<double> operator+(const std::vector<double>& a, const std::vector<double>& b)
    {
        assert(a.size() == b.size());

        int size = a.size();

        std::vector<double> result;
        result.reserve(size);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        {
            result.push_back(0);
            result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        }

        return result;
    }

    //sum of matrices
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> operator+(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& a, const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& b)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        assert(a.size() == b.size());
#endif

        int size = a.size();

#ifdef _DEBUG
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        {
            assert(a[i].size() == b[i].size());
        }
#endif

        std::vector<std::vector<double>> result;
        result.resize(size);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        {
            result.push_back(a[i] + b[i]);
        }

        return result;
    }


    //subtraction of vectors
    std::vector<double> operator-(const std::vector<double>& a, const std::vector<double>& b)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        assert(a.size() == b.size());
#endif

        int size = a.size();

        std::vector<double> result;
        result.resize(size);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        {
            result[i] = a[i] - b[i];
        }

        return result;
    }

    //subtraction of matrices (calls subtraction of vectors)
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> operator-(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& a, const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& b)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        assert(a.size() == b.size());
#endif

        int size = a.size();

#ifdef _DEBUG
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        {
            assert(a[i].size() == b[i].size());
        }
#endif

        std::vector<std::vector<double>> result;
        result.resize(size);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        {
            result.push_back(a[i] - b[i]);
        }

        return result;
    }

    //elementwise division
    std::vector<double> operator/(const std::vector<double>& a, const std::vector<double>& b)
    {
        assert(a.size() == b.size());

        int size = a.size();

        std::vector<double> result;
        result.reserve(size);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        {
            if(b[i] < MIN_NUMBER_TOLERANCE)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Can't divide by zero!");
            }
            result[i] = a[i] / b[i];
        }

        return result;
    }

    double neuralnetwork::costDerivatives(const double &networkOutput , const double &expectedOutput)
    {
        return expectedOutput - networkOutput;
    }

    std::vector<double> neuralnetwork::costDerivatives(const std::vector<double> &networkOutput , const std::vector<double> &expectedOutput)
    {
        assert(expectedOutput.size() == networkOutput.size());
        int size = networkOutput.size();
        std::vector<double> output;
        output.reserve(size);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        {
            output.push_back(networkOutput[i] - expectedOutput[i]);
        }

        return output;
    }

    void neuralnetwork::backPropagation(const std::vector<double> &neuralNetworkInputs , const std::vector<double> &expectedOutputs, // inputs
                                        std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>& derivativeWeights , std::vector<std::vector<double>>& derivativeBiases) // outputs
    {


        std::cout << "teste "<< counter++ << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");



        derivativeWeights.reserve( sizes.size() - 1 );
        derivativeBiases.reserve( sizes.size() - 1 );

        //to store one activation layer
        std::vector<double> activation = neuralNetworkInputs;
        //to store each one of the activation layers
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> activations;

        activations.reserve(sizes.size()); // numBiases is the same as the number of neurons (except 1st layer)
        activations.push_back(activation);
        int maxLayerSize = 0;


        std::cout << "teste "<< counter++ << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");




        for ( int i = 1 ; i < numBiases ; i++ )
        {
            maxLayerSize = std::max(sizes[i], maxLayerSize);
        }


        std::cout << "teste "<< counter++ << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");




        // to store one weighted sum
        std::vector<double> z;
        z.reserve(maxLayerSize);
        // to store each one of the weighted sums
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> zs;
        zs.reserve(sizes.size());

        // layer and neuron counter
        int layer, neuron;

        for ( layer = 1 ; layer < numLayers ; layer++ )
        {
            z = (weights[layer] * activation) + biases[layer];
            zs.push_back(z);
            activation = sigmoid(z);
            activations.push_back(activation);
        }


        std::cout << "teste "<< counter++ << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");




        std::vector<double> delta = costDerivatives(activations[ lastIndex( activations , 1 )] , expectedOutputs) * sigmoid_prime(z);
        delta.reserve(maxLayerSize);

        derivativeBiases.push_back(delta);

        int j;

        std::vector<std::vector<double>> dummyMatrix;
        dummyMatrix.reserve(maxLayerSize);


        for (neuron = 0; neuron < sizes[ lastIndex( sizes , 1 )]; neuron++)
        {
            dummyMatrix.push_back(std::vector<double>(activations[ lastIndex( activations , 2 )].size()));
            for (j = 0; j < activations[ lastIndex( activations , 2 )].size(); j++)
            {
                dummyMatrix[neuron][j] = delta[neuron] * activations[ lastIndex( activations , 2 )][j];
            }
        }


        std::cout << "teste "<< counter++ << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");



        derivativeWeights.push_back(dummyMatrix);
        dummyMatrix.clear();

        std::vector<double> sp;
        sp.reserve(maxLayerSize);

        std::vector<double> dummyVector;
        dummyVector.reserve(maxLayerSize);

        double dummyDouble = 0;

        for(layer = 2 ; layer < numLayers ; layer++)
        {
            z = zs[ lastIndex( zs , layer )];
            sp = sigmoid_prime(z);

            for(j = 0 ; j < sizes[ lastIndex( weights , layer )] ; j++)
            {
                for (neuron = 0; neuron < sizes[ lastIndex( sizes , layer - 1 )]; neuron++)
                {
                    dummyDouble += weights[ lastIndex( weights , layer - 1 )][neuron][j] * delta[neuron];
                }
                dummyVector.push_back(dummyDouble * sp[j]);
                dummyDouble = 0;
            }
            delta = dummyVector;
            dummyVector.clear();

            derivativeBiases.push_back(delta);

            for (neuron = 0; neuron < sizes[ lastIndex( sizes , layer )]; neuron++)
            {
                dummyMatrix.push_back(std::vector<double>(sizes[ lastIndex( sizes , layer + 1 )]));
                for (j = 0; j < sizes[ lastIndex( sizes , layer + 1 )]; j++)
                {
                    dummyMatrix[neuron][j] = activations[ lastIndex( activations , layer + 1 )][j] * delta[neuron];
                }
            }
            derivativeWeights.push_back(dummyMatrix);
            dummyMatrix.clear();
        }


        std::cout << "teste "<< counter++ << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");




        //both derivativeWeights and derivativeBiases are reversed. so let's reverse it.
        std::reverse(derivativeWeights.begin(),derivativeWeights.end());
        std::reverse(derivativeBiases.begin(),derivativeBiases.end());


        std::cout << "teste "<< counter++ << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");




    }
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "neuralnetwork.h"
#include <string>

void printAll(const std::vector<double> & v, const std::string & name)
{
    int size = v.size();

    std::cout << "\t" <<  name << ":\t";

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        std::cout << v[i] << "\t";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void printAll(const std::vector<T> & v, const std::string & name)
{
    int size = v.size();

    std::cout << name << ":" << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        printAll(v[i], "\t" + ("[" + std::to_string(i)) + "]");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{

    nn::neuralnetwork n({2,4,3});

    n.weights = {{},{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8}} , {{9,8,7,6},{5,4,3,2},{1,2,3,4}}};
    n.biases = {{},{1, 4, 6, 8} , {9, 2, 4}};

    printAll(n.weights,"weights");
    printAll(n.biases,"biases");

    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> derivativeWeights;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> derivativeBiases;
    n.backPropagation({1,2},{1,2,3},derivativeWeights,derivativeBiases);

    printAll(n.derivativeWeights,"derivativeWeights");
    printAll(n.derivativeBiases,"derivativeBiases");

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question? This should be stated in the question body, above. Also, is this the smallest chunk of code that reproduces the problem? A wall of text is not going to attract good answers.

Comment: There's an awful lot of code there to look through. Generally problems which affect release mode but not debug mode come down to using uninitialised variables.

Comment: Did you try to compile with g++ and -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG flag (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_using.html#debug_mode.using.mode for further info) to perform bound checking for operator[]?

Comment: @jdv, I understand and agree with you, but i didn't realize how to ask this question in other (better/proper) way.

Comment: @bennji_of_the_overflow, yes really seems like this is the problem, but I just walk through the code and couldn't find a uninitialized variable...

Comment: @PicaudVincent, I didn't know about it. I'll certainly try it!.

Comment: @HenriqueGarcia see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @jdv I just deleted 2 functions that are not used.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is that you are only reserving memory for the vectors in the constructor, not allocating it.

The reserve method does not resize the vector, it is a performance optimization in cases where you know you will resize the vector in the future, but an optimizing compiler is free to ignore it.

This isn't causing a problem for 'weights' and 'biases' in this particular code becuase you are initializing them with vectors of the proper size, which does set them to the correct size. The problems are with derivativeWeights and derivativeBiases, where you reserve memory for the vectors, but they are never actually resized. This makes this memory potentially invalid if you try to dereference it. You could use resize instead of reserve, or push back the elements one by one, which will also resize the vector.

Another comment is that you don't have to use this-> for every member of the class, the 'this->' is assumed for members of the class if you don't use it.

Comment: Inside the backpropagation method (neuralnetwork.cpp), I use push_back to resize the vector. I don't used resize because it would make the vector allocate more memory than it will use.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found the problem, but I realised that, for this problem (artificial neural network), I can initialize each property of the class with each right sizes without loss of generality. So this is what I'm going to do.

I feel a little ashamed that I am not finding it... :/